# Response status check using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to check response status by using following code:

```
$scope.coach = Coach.get(function(response) {
    if(response.status === 401) {
    alert("Coach");
    }
});
```

but its not working, can anyone help please. thanks

Comment: What exactly is `Coach`? A service injected into your controller? You'll need to include its code for this to make sense.

Comment: yes, Coach is injected by controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$resource.get()` takes two callbacks; the second is the error handler and receives the response object:

```
$scope.coach = Coach.get(
  function (coach) {
    // ... could do something with returned data object here
  },
  function (res) {
    alert("Coach status: " + res.status);
  }
);
```

Check this plunker for a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/WHL63r?p=preview

Comment: thanks alot, i have found my solution from your given example.